# New to JS/JQuery Trying to get the ID of a Table Row and getting "undefined" instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking for some other codes here, and I did get usefull information. But I must be doing something wrong and I don't get what is my problem.

Here is my HTML table generator:

```
foreach ( $obj as $key => $client ) {
        $tpl .= "
            <tr id=data-'{$client->id}'>
                <td>{$client->id}</td>
                <td>{$client->nombre}</td>
                <td>{$client->apellido1}</td>
                <td>{$client->apellido2}</td>
                <td>{$client->direccion}</td>
                <td>{$client->codigoPostal}</td>
                <td>{$client->fechaNacimiento}</td>
                <td>{$client->notas}</td>
                <td>{$client->fechaRegistro}</td>
                <td><input id='eliminar' name='eliminar' type='submit' value='Eliminar'></td>
            </tr>";
    }
```

And here is my JS file, who tries to get the TR ID:

```
var trid = null;
var $this = $(this);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tablaDatos tr td:not(:last-child").click(function () {
        var trid = $this.closest('tr').data('id');
        alert(trid);
    });
});
```

To clarify the code: I am getting the table generated through all the DB info.
tablaDatos is the ID for the whole table (headers+the pasted code)
I want the input to not make any action when clicked. But all the row performs the same action (alerting the TR ID atm).

Comment: `$this` ==> `$(this)` **Code:** `$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')`

Comment: $this.closest('tr').data('id') change this to $this.closest('tr')[0].id

Comment: and `id` attribute different than `data-id`

Comment: Thanks guys! worked perfectly. Can't upvote since im too new here, but @Tushar 's answer was correct.

Comment: @Tushar please post as answer

Comment: `id=data-'{$client->id}'` looks suspect... did you mean `id='data-{$client->id}'`?

Comment: Yup, i meant that anyways i pasted an old version, actual one dosent even have 'data' but you are right :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as follow.

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')
```

1. `$(this)` is the element on which the event has fired
2. `closest('tr')` will select the closest ancestor matching the passed selector
3. `attr('id')` will get the `id` attribute value